# Broken query Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these two tables

- **personal_details** (`id, name, surname, date_of_birth`)
- **employee** (`id, hire_date`)

I need to set the `hire_date` on the `employee` table to the `date_of_birth` + 10 years.

```
UPDATE employee E
SET E.date_hire = add_months(D.date_of_birth, 120);
FROM employee E, personal_details D
WHERE E.ID = D.ID
```

It's so odd that it is not working, anyone can see something there ?

Comment: yeah its not working for somereason

Comment: That's not an error. I mean concrete error messages.

Comment: Did you check the manual for the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder what company starts hiring people of 10 years old, but ok.

```
UPDATE employee E
SET E.date_hire = 
    (SELECT
      add_months(D.date_birth, 120)
    FROM
      personal_details D
    WHERE
      D.ID = E.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this:

```
UPDATE employee E
SET E.date_hire = COALESCE(
    ( SELECT add_months(D.date_of_birth, 120)
      FROM personal_details D
      WHERE E.ID = D.ID
    ), E.date_hire) ;
```

or this - which I find more intuitive:

```
UPDATE 
  ( SELECT E.date_hire, add_months(D.date_of_birth, 120) AS new_date_hire
    FROM employee E
      JOIN personal_details D
        ON E.ID = D.ID
  )
SET E.date_hire = new_date_hire ;
```

Comment: Introducing the coalesce for what reason?

Comment: @GolezTrol: The `COALESCE()` is to to ensure that the `E.date_hire` will not be updated (with `NULL`) when there is no matching row in the `personal_details` table.

Comment: I understand that, but it's not in the specs and it could hide the fact that personal details are missing.

Comment: @GolezTrol: I think it is as the OP is tryng to do an (implicit) join that would not change any non-matching rows.

Comment: Ok, you could be right about that.

Answer (score 0):

employee (id,**hire_date**,salary,bonus)

SET E.**date_hire**

The column names don't match.

Answer (score 0):

You say the column name is hire_date and then set a column called date_hire

```
UPDATE employee E 
SET E.date_hire = add_months(D.date_birth, 120);
```

You have a semi colon at the end of that statement which means the rest of the sql is treated as separate

You need to include a `SELECT` to actually retrieve the data

You'll be a lot closer when you've got that lot sorted  :-)

(I chose not to just give the sql)